# Arduino + ultrasonic rangefinder behaving unexpectedly

Tags: audio

I'm using an [HC-SR04 ultrasonic rangefinder](http://www.micropik.com/PDF/HCSR04.pdf) to control the frequency at which an Arduino pin turns on and off, with the output going via a 1/4" jack plug into my computer's audio interface. (i.e. it's a simple audio oscillator that responds to gestures). This is the code (based on that given [here](http://www.circuitbasics.com/how-to-set-up-an-ultrasonic-range-finder-on-an-arduino/)):

```
#define trigPin 10
#define echoPin 12


void setup() {

  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {

  float duration, distance;
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW); // Sends a 2 µs LOW signal to the trigPin     
  delayMicroseconds(30);

  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH); // Sends a 10 µs HIGH signal to the trigPin
  delayMicroseconds(30);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH); //Defines the duration variable


  digitalWrite(9, HIGH); //square wave oscillator 
  delay(0.1+duration*0.01);
  digitalWrite(9, LOW);
  delay(0.1+duration*0.01);
}
```

Pin 9 is the output, and sounds roughly as expected, but what's confusing me is that making any kind of gesture other than very slow ones (i.e. if the distance isn't changing very slowly) causes the output to stop completely for a few seconds, then start again, as if something is overloading and then resetting. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @DaveTweed: I reckon this shouldn't have been migrated. The problem is probably in the hardware specification. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not really understand the behaviour of your program, but I would
like to point out a couple of points that may be problematic:

1. Your comment says “Sends a 10 µs HIGH signal to the trigPin”, just as
   the program you based yours on, yet you have a 30 µs delay. If
   this extra delay makes you miss the rising edge on the echo pin, then
   `pulseIn()` will believe it is seen the *previous* pulse, and it will
   wait for the next raising edge before starting its measurement. Since
   that next rising edge will never happen, `pulseIn()` will eventually
   time out after one second. This is probably the silence you are
   hearing.
2. Your sound frequency may not be what you expect, because the time
   needed to run through the loop is not only the two calls to
   `delay()`, but also the time taken by `pulseIn()` and the various
   `delayMicroseconds()`. You should have more consistent timings if you
   use the `tone()` function instead of trying to bit-bang the sound.

Answer (score 0):

Your comments don't match your timing delay values and the datasheet specifies a 10 µs pulse. You're giving it 30 µs but you might get away with it.

I'd look at how often you're triggering the device.

[image]

*Figure 1. Don't trigger the device more frequently than 40 times per second.*